# Creating a recursive ffmpeg converter

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a script of some sort that will convert any video files it detects within a folder (also scanning subfolders), to an .avi file of the same name, in the same place, then remove the original file. I've not really used cmd much for any programming/scripting so I'm stumbling over what I suspect is some pretty simple syntax issues.

If anyone is familiar with encoding and ffmpeg, please point out whether the encoding options are wrong (I'm stumbling about in the dark at the moment).

Using [this thread](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/356314-How-to-batch-convert-multiplex-any-files-with-ffmpeg), I'm working with something currently resembling:

```
dir/b/s *.(mkv|mp4|m4v|wmv) >listing.txt  #Make a list of all the files with certain extensions, for reading.
for /F "delims=;" %%F in (listing.txt) do ffmpeg.exe  -i "%%F" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "%%~na.avi"
#Then to delete original files
for /F "delims=;" %%F in (listing.txt) do del %%F
del listing.txt
```

The first issue I have is that I'd like to be able to populate the list with all the common video types. I'm imagining cmd has some syntax similar to perl string matching e.g. `A(B|C)` would match AB and AC that I could mimic for matching any video file extension? (I've written it in the code above to illustrate the point but I know it doesn't work).

I hope that is enough to try and illustrate what I'm attempting.

Comment: Why AVI and not a more modern container format such as MP4 which is commonly used for H.264 video? Also, the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-c:a aac -strict experimental`) may sound better at 128k than `libvo_aacenc`.

Comment: Purely for the reason that I want to stream these files reliably to another device (namely an X360) and it doesn't play all encoding variants of mp4, but does of avi - at least in my experiences in the past.

Answer (score 0):

dir *.ext1 *.ext2

however better to specify full paths and use quotes if expecting spaces in names.

```
Dir "%userprofile%\documents\*.avi" "%userprofile%\documents\*.mp4" /a /s /b
```

Easier than `For` is the `forfiles` command. But not suitable for multiple file types.

It can also be one line

```
@for /f "usebackq delims=" %A in (`dir "%Userprofile%\documents\*.avi" "%Userprofile%\documents\*.mp4" /a /s /b`)  do @echo %A
```

Use %%A in a batch file and %A if typing the command.

Comment: Great than you, that pretty much achieves what I was after. Would you happen to know why I an error saying `%%F was unexpected at this time` ?

Comment: Because I use %%A and you use %%F. Make sure all %%F are %%A or vice versa.

Comment: Yeah your last point got it, I was testing by inputting directly to the prompt and it was complaining about double %.

Comment: Last problem before I think this is pretty much solved in that case, currently the code I have as above is giving the output file the name `%%~na.avi` instead of parsing the input files name and just changing the extension. What am I missing here?

Comment: Case has to be the same %%a is different to %%A. `%%~nA` or F if you are using that.